# Java - Open SSH client and send command

Tags: java, ssh, putty

I'm building an app that needed to open a new SSH connection for the user, and then send automatically a command.
The app need to run on Windows, i thought about using putty to the SSH client and then send the command but the command don't sent to putty.
Anyone have any idea how can i implement this?

This is my code:

```
String command = puttyPath + " -ssh user@localhost"
process =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
writer.write(secondCommand);
writer.flush();
process.waitFor(600_000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is there any possible to send only one command to putty and the putty will know to send it to the remote server?

Comment: what server you are using?

Comment: @LAIDANIYoucef Linux machine

Comment: why you want putty, i don't think you need putty try to use `command = "ssh ipadress yourcommand";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add for your command the "-m" and a file with secondCommand.
For more read about [enter link description here](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-eventlog)

Answer (score 1):

PuTTY is a GUI application. Do not try to automate it.

Use the [Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) instead. It's a console application from PuTTY package.

It supports input streams, what you code attempts to use. And also it allows support specifying the command on its command line:

```
String command = plinkPath + " -ssh user@localhost " + secondCommand;
```

---

Though even that is not the correct approach. Use some native Java SSH library, like the [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), instead of using an external application.

See the [JSch `Exec.java` example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html).

Comment: I want to show the terminal of putty, i didn't succeeded to do so with plink

Comment: If you want to display terminal, you should say so in the question.